# tagging points in 3D matrix - there must be a more elegant solution to this

Tags: r, spatial, euclidean-distance

I have two datasets with X,Y,Z coordinates, dfA and dFB, and I want to add a column with a variable from dfB to dfA if the distance between the points is less than some value d.

here's an example of the data that I'm trying to work with (in reality dfA and dfB will have over 1000 rows each):

```
dfA<-data.frame(matrix(ncol=5, nrow=40))
names(dfA) <- c("ID","G","x","y", "z")

dfA$ID<-round(runif(40, min=10, max=50),0)
dfA$G<-round(runif(40, min=0.5, max=15),3)
dfA$x<-round(runif(40, min=0, max=100),1)
dfA$y<-round(runif(40, min=0, max=100),1)
dfA$z<-round(runif(40, min=0, max=100),1)


dfB<-data.frame(matrix(ncol=5, nrow=20))
names(dfB) <- c("ID","TPH","x","y", "z")

dfB$ID<-round(runif(20, min=100, max=200),0)
dfB$TPH<-round(runif(20, min=100, max=1000),0)
dfB$x<-round(runif(20, min=0, max=100),1)
dfB$y<-round(runif(20, min=0, max=100),1)
dfB$z<-round(runif(20, min=0, max=100),1)
```

so what I would like to get is a dfB$TPH value for each dfA$ID if the points are at some minimum distance. Ideally I'd also like to get the dfB$ID and the distance between those points.

this is what I have figured out but I'm hoping there is a more elegant solution to this...

```
library(flexclust)
d<-as.data.frame(dist2(dfA[,3:5],dfB[,3:5]))
colnames(d)<-dfB$ID
dfD<- as.data.table(d)

library(data.table)

dfD<-dfD[, MAX := colnames(.SD)[max.col(.SD, ties.method="first")]]
dfD<-dfD[, MIN2 := colnames(.SD)[which.min(.SD)], by = 1:nrow(dfD)]
dfD<-cbind(dfA["ID"],dfD)
View(dfD)


dfD<-cbind(dfA,dfD)
dfD$di<-0
dfD$TPH<-0
n.smp<-nrow(dfD)

for (i in 1:n.smp){
  j<-dfD[i,"MIN2"]
  dfD[i,"di"]<-dfD[i,j]
  xx<-dfB$TPH[dfB$ID == j]
  dfD[i,"TPH"]<-xx
}
```

at this point I can filter out the points in dfA without close enough dfB points but this seems clunky and I'm not looking forward to doing this on my real data.

Any advice?

Many Thanks